# What's the right way to read the cmake package description in `Findxxx.cmake`?

Tags: cmake

When countered with unfamiliar packages, I need to read the `Findxxx.cmake` to figure out the pre-defined cached variable. For example, in `FindBoost.cmake`, the starting lines are like this:

```
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-Clause License.  See accompanying
# file Copyright.txt or https://cmake.org/licensing for details.

#[=======================================================================[.rst:
FindBoost
---------

Find Boost include dirs and libraries

Use this module by invoking :command:`find_package` with the form:

.. code-block:: cmake

  find_package(Boost
    [version] [EXACT]      # Minimum or EXACT version e.g. 1.67.0
    [REQUIRED]             # Fail with error if Boost is not found
    [COMPONENTS <libs>...] # Boost libraries by their canonical name
                           # e.g. "date_time" for "libboost_date_time"
    [OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS <libs>...]
                           # Optional Boost libraries by their canonical name)
    )                      # e.g. "date_time" for "libboost_date_time"
```

The description is written in `.rst`, but I don't know what's the right way to read it except for open it using vim.

My ideal way to read is using command line like `cmake-show-module boost`, then a viewer pops out. Or using vscode, hovering `find_package(BOOST)`, then the description pops out. How can I achieve it?

Comment: `cmake --help-module FindBoost` would print the information from the rst section of the FindBoost module on the console. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @vre Thanks! That's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake's `Find<module>` files contain their documentation in reStructuredText (rst) format. The [online documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/) is generated from this data and can be easily viewed with a browser, e.g. using for the `FindBoost` module the address `https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html`.

To view the documentation from the command line you can use

```
cmake --help-module FindBoost
```

For other CMake find modules replace `Boost` with the appropriate module name, for instance `Qt`.